# Find the document in mongodb that has an item at a specific index of array using python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have database like;

```
ObjectID(234567654rtfgjytrfgfgf){
       _id : "3456ytgfewrtyhgfd"
       Categories:{
             [0] : "Apple"
             [1] : "Mango"
       }
}
ObjectID(23dfghjthrgytrfgfgf){
       _id : "67tghjgfdrthg"
       Categories:{
             [0] : "Orange"
             [1] : "Mango"
       }
}
ObjectID(23dfghjthrgytrfgfgf){
       _id : "67tghjgfdrthg"
       Categories:{
             [0] : "Apple"
             [1] : "Mango"
       }
}
```

I want to find the document that has the `Apple` at a `0th` index of category array in `Mongo` database document using python. I am trying in this way;

```
cursor = collection.find({"Categories" : "Apple"})
        for document in cursor:
            print(document)
```

It is printing the same result but **how can I specify the index of Categories array?** I am not specifying the categories index in `collection.find({"Categories" : "Apple"})`

Answer (score 1):

to match only index 0:

```
cursor = collection.find({"Categories.0" : "Apple"})
for document in cursor:
    print(document)
```